# exporting from/importing to numpy, scipy in SQLite and HDF5 formats

Tags: python, sqlite, numpy, scipy, hdf5

There seems to be many choices for Python to interface with SQLite (sqlite3, atpy) and HDF5 (h5py, pyTables) -- I wonder if anyone has experience using these together with numpy arrays or data tables (structured/record arrays), and which of these most seamlessly integrate with "scientific" modules (numpy, scipy) for each data format (SQLite and HDF5).

Comment: Are you asking about saving numpy data to SQLite tables?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most of it depends on your use case.

I have a lot more experience dealing with the various HDF5-based methods than traditional relational databases, so I can't comment too much on SQLite libraries for python...

At least as far as `h5py` vs `pyTables`, they both offer very seamless access via numpy arrays, but they're oriented towards very different use cases.

If you have n-dimensional data that you want to quickly access an arbitrary *index-based* slice of, then it's much more simple to use `h5py`.  If you have data that's more table-like, and you want to query it, then `pyTables` is a much better option.

`h5py` is a relatively "vanilla" wrapper around the HDF5 libraries compared to `pyTables`.  This is a very good thing if you're going to be regularly accessing your HDF file from another language (`pyTables` adds some extra metadata).  `h5py` can do a *lot*, but for some use cases (e.g. what `pyTables` does) you're going to need to spend more time tweaking things.

`pyTables` has some *really* nice features.  However, if your data doesn't look much like a table, then it's probably not the best option.

To give a more concrete example, I work a lot with fairly large (tens of GB) 3 and 4 dimensional arrays of data.  They're homogenous arrays of floats, ints, uint8s, etc.  I usually want to access a small subset of the entire dataset.  `h5py` makes this *very* simple, and does a fairly good job of auto-guessing a reasonable chunk size.  Grabbing an arbitrary chunk or slice from disk is much, much faster than for a simple memmapped file. (Emphasis on arbitrary... Obviously, if you want to grab an entire "X" slice, then a C-ordered memmapped array is impossible to beat, as all the data in an "X" slice are adjacent on disk.)

As a counter example, my wife collects data from a wide array of sensors that sample at minute to second intervals over several years. She needs to store and run arbitrary querys (and relatively simple calculations) on her data.  `pyTables` makes this use case very easy and fast, and still has some advantages over traditional relational databases. (Particularly in terms of disk usage and speed at which a large (index-based) chunk of data can be read into memory)

Comment: Thanks -- this is exactly the kind of information I was looking for in contrasting `h5py` and `pyTables`... but so then it's not necessarily which goes with NumPy but which goes well with the actual data in the NumPy array. I'll post the `SQLite` part as a separate question.

Comment: @JoeKington: Side note: I'm not sure that "C-ordered memmapped array is impossible to beat": copying data with memcpy() can be slower than transferring compressed data and decompressing it when it arrives in the processor (http://blosc.pytables.org/trac).  The net effect is that processing compressed array data can be faster than processing uncompressed array data.