# How can I save a big `numpy` as '*.npz' array with limited filesystem capacity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, low-memory

I have a `numpy` array which saved as an uncompressed '*npz' file is about   26 GiB as it is `numpy.float32` and `numpy.savez()` ends with:

```
OSError: Failed to write to /tmp/tmpl9v3xsmf-numpy.npy: 6998400000 requested and 3456146404 written
```

I suppose saving it compressed may save the day, but with `numpy.savez_compressed()` I have also:

```
OSError: Failed to write to /tmp/tmp591cum2r-numpy.npy: 6998400000 requested and 3456157668 written
```

as `numpy.savez_compressed()` saves the array uncompressed first.

The obvious "use additional storage" I do not consider an answer. ;)

[EDIT]

The tag `low-memory` refers to disk memory, not RAM.

Comment: What kind of data you're preserving in that array?

Comment: @Kasramvd floats, specifically `numpy.float32`

Comment: What if you try to save it as an hdf5 file? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928136/input-and-output-numpy-arrays-to-h5py

Comment: Can't you use a lighter format like `float16`, `int8`, `uint8`, etc.?

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel It is worth a try if I find no way of saving it as '*.npz'. A lot of code depends on the format.

Comment: @Kasramvd unfortunately not, I have already moved from `float16` as it lacked precision.

Comment: @abukaj then, most likely you'll have to chunk your array into smaller pieces. Although I find it strange that you can have it all in memory but not on disk.

Comment: Maybe you could pass a [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) object as file to `np.savez`.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel I agree. I have 62.9G of RAM and 13 G of `/` (which also makes me worry why I am unable to save 6.9 G there)

Comment: If you have such a big array and need that precision, that _is_ how much it takes to store it. The only way you could really reduce it (besides generic compression) is if there are known patterns in the data, e.g. is it a sparse array, or are there repeated or derived values? If all the values have about the same exponent maybe storing only the mantissa in `int16`/`uint16` could be enough? Also, do you know what is your file system? It may limit the size of the files that you can store.

Comment: If you keep your machine running, maybe an in-memory filesystem could also be useful. There is, of course, quite some risk of losing your data if the machine goes down unexpectedly.

Comment: @swenzel, ...unfortunately, `.npz` files are zip files, and zip format was built with an expectation of ability to `seek()`, so I don't expect writing directly to a gzip object (which is effectively append-only for purpose of writes) to work. Saving to tmpfs or another in-RAM filesystem, and only then moving the content to fixed-disk, is more appropriate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well, I suppose then you have to save it to a BytesIO object first, then compress that. Which, due to memroy demand, is probably no solution either...

Comment: @swenzel Indeed, it is - I have already implemented it. It causes my system to swap, but let me save my data.

Comment: Which version of Python? I believe a more efficient solution is available with Python 3.6 or newer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 3.6 I have already replaced `io.BytesIO()` with `ZipFile.open(..., mode='w')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the addition of `ZipFile.open(..., mode='w')` in Python 3.6, you can do better:

```
import numpy as np
import zipfile
import io

def saveCompressed(fh, **namedict):
     with zipfile.ZipFile(fh, mode="w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,
                          allowZip64=True) as zf:
         for k, v in namedict.items():
             with zf.open(k + '.npy', 'w', force_zip64=True) as buf:
                 np.lib.npyio.format.write_array(buf,
                                                 np.asanyarray(v),
                                                 allow_pickle=False)
```

Comment: Looks almost exactly as implementation I am testing right now, with the exception of `with zf.open(k + '.npy', mode='w', force_zip64=True) as buf:`

Comment: Using `zf.open()` is the key difference, since it allows the file created inside the zip to be written incrementally (thus, with a sane ZipFile implementation, with bounded memory usage).

Comment: I mean the `, force_zip64=True` part.

Comment: Your code ends with `ValueError: Can't close the ZIP file while there is an open writing handle on it. Close the writing handle before closing the zip.`. I guess it is about the size of the array. Would you mind to include the `frorce_zip64=True` part in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Note: **I would be more than happy to accept a more RAM-efficient solution.**

I have browsed the `numpy.savez_compressed()` code and decided to reimplement part of its functionality:

```
import numpy as np
import zipfile
import io

def saveCompressed(fh, **namedict):
     with zipfile.ZipFile(fh,
                          mode="w",
                          compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,
                          allowZip64=True) as zf:
         for k, v in namedict.items():
             buf = io.BytesIO()
             np.lib.npyio.format.write_array(buf,
                                             np.asanyarray(v),
                                             allow_pickle=False)
             zf.writestr(k + '.npy',
                         buf.getvalue())
```

It causes my system to swap, but at least I am able to store my data (sham data used in the example):

```
>>> A = np.ones(12 * 6 * 6 * 1 * 6 * 6 * 10000* 5* 9, dtype=np.float32)
>>> saveCompressed(open('test.npz', 'wb'), A=A)
>>> A = np.load('test.npz')['A']
>>> A.shape
(6998400000,)
>>> (A == 1).all()
True
```