# What is a good way to create a simple database to store and load a random number of high-dimensional numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

A computation process create a random number of numpy arrays and I want to save and load each array conveniently to the hard-disk. Importantly, the files are high dimensional and the shape of the array is random itself.

To save and load each array, I create the following interface:

```
class Filesaver:

    def __init__(self, filename: str):
        self._filename = filename
        try:
            f = open(self._filename, 'rb')
            self._pos = self._get_len(f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self._pos = 0

    def _get_len(self, file) -> int:
        pos = 0
        while True:
            try:
                pickle.load(file)
                pos += 1
            except EOFError:
                break
        return pos

    def save(self, data: np.ndarray) -> None:
        """Pickles the obejct to hdd """
        with open(self._filename, 'ab+') as f:
            pickle.dump(data, f)
            self._pos += 1

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> np.ndarray:
        assert idx < self._pos, EOFError("File is not long enough")
        with open(self._filename, 'rb') as f:
            tmp = 0
            while tmp <= idx:
                data = pickle.load(f)
                tmp += 1
        return data

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self._pos
```

The interface allows appending another array to the existing database and also loading each element. However, the approach seems a bit strange to me: First, to load a array with the `__getitem__` method, I have to cycle through the file and cannot open element `idx` directly. Second, the initial number of elements in the save object is determined in the `_get_len` method cycling through the file until an error occurs.

Does anybody have a better idea to save and load a random number (high-dimensional) of numpy arrays to and from the hard-disk?

Comment: What about `np.save()`, and `np.load()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [h5py](http://www.h5py.org) (or alternatively [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/)).

You will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20938742/1453508) a short example of how to use h5py. Further documentation is available on its website.