# saving a list of numpy arrays with different dimensions in python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, save

I have a list of numpy arrays with different dimensions that I want to save. I can always save each numpy array in this list as an npz file. My problem is that beforehand, I wouldn't know how many arrays there are in this list. If I try saving this list into an npz file and attempt to load this list, I get

```
Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

What is a recommended way to save this list?

I'm coming from MATLAB wherein you can save cell arrays, structs, matrices into a single .mat file and I'm wondering what the equivalent would be here in python.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of doing this in Numpy but in Pandas, by using [HDF5](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/) format you can store multiple files to the same file. You need to add different keys to the elements. Here is some example from a different question that use numpy and hdf5 [Input and output numpy arrays to h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928136/input-and-output-numpy-arrays-to-h5py)