# Loading columnar-structured time-series data faster into a NumPy Arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, fastparquet

> Hi! Are there any ways to load large, (ideally) compressed, and columnar-structured data faster into NumPy arrays in Python?  Considering common solutions such as Pandas, Apache Parquet/Feather and HDF5, I am struggling to find a suiting way for my (time-series) problem.
>
> As was expected, representing my data as NumPy array yields, by far, the fastest execution time for search problems such as binary search, significantly outperforming the same analysis when applied on a Pandas dataframe instead. On the other hand, when I try to store my data as `npz` files, for instance, directly loading the `npz` into NumPy arrays takes much longer compared to loading the same data into a Dataframe using the `fasterparquet` engine and the columnar-storage in `.parquet`. This loading, however, requires me to call `.to_numpy()` on the resulting dataframe, which now again causes heavy delays in accessing the underlying numpy representation of the dataframe.

As mentioned above, one alternative I tried was to store the data in a format, that can be loaded without any intermediate conversion steps into a numpy array. However, loading time appears to be much slower when the  data is stored as `.npz` file (table with > 10M records and > 10 columns) compared to the same data stored as `.parquet` file.

Comment: Try saving to h5 file, using the `h5py` library. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928136/input-and-output-numpy-arrays-to-h5py#:~:text=h5py%20provides%20a%20model%20of%20datasets%20and%20groups.%20the%20former%20is%20basically%20arrays%20and%20the%20latter%20you%20can%20think%20of%20as%20directories.%20each%20is%20named.%20you%20should%20look%20at%20the%20documentation%20for%20the%20api%20and%20examples%3A)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, fastparquet supports loading your data into a dictionary of numpy arrays, if you set these up before hand. This is a "hidden" feature. If you give details of the dtype and size of the data you wish to load. this answer can be edited accordingly.

> to call .to_numpy() on the resulting dataframe, which now again causes heavy delays

This is very surprising, it should normally be a copy-free view of the same underlying data.