# Could someone explain what is happening in this code to save a numpy array as a binary file?

Tags: arrays, numpy, format, pickle, binaryfiles

I've been using the pickle library to read and write numpy arrays but they tend to be very large. In my quest for finding out if there was a better way, I found Mark's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619199/best-way-to-preserve-numpy-arrays-on-disk/41425878#41425878) page (the one with the chart). Basically, storing it as a binary file appears to not only be the fastest and reading and writing, but also takes among the smallest amount of memory. So I clicked on [his github link](https://github.com/mverleg/array_storage_benchmark/blob/master/methods.py) and found on line 96 the code I believe he uses to save the ndarrays. His code is:

```
class Binary(TimeArrStorage):
    def save(self, arr, pth):
        with open(pth, 'wb+') as fh:
            fh.write(b'{0:s} {1:d} {2:d}\n'.format(arr.dtype, *arr.shape))
            fh.write(arr.data)
            sync(fh)

    def load(self, pth):
        with open(pth, 'rb') as fh:
            dtype, w, h = str(fh.readline()).split()
            return frombuffer(fh.read(), dtype=dtype).reshape((int(w), int(h)))
```

My specific questions are, what is the meaning of the string passed to the first call to fh.write? I assume the preceding "b" means binary, but what about the {0:s} {1:d} {2:d}, especially since there are only two parameters inside the parenthesis after format. Second question is can this method be used for ndarrays of any data type? Third question is, do I need to call the sync method (method is defined at the top of the github page)? And last question is, I looked up what arr.data returns if arr is an ndarray and it's basically a memory location to where the data begins, so how does this code know it's reached the end of the object it's trying to write?

Comment: `.format` is a string formatting method that was introduced with Python3.  The older method used `%` etc.  `np.save/load` should produce about the same size files.  They use a fixed size prelimnary buffer to store shape and dtype information (something like 80 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

I have (from another question)

```
In [509]: arr
Out[509]: 
array([[-1.0856306 ,  0.99734545],
       [ 0.2829785 , -1.50629471],
       [-0.57860025,  1.65143654]])
```

I can format a string with its attributes:

```
In [510]: '%s %d %d'%(arr.dtype, *arr.shape)
Out[510]: 'float64 3 2'
```

The format in your example gives an error in py3 (it's ok in py2):

```
In [500]: '{0:s} {1:d} {2:d}'.format(arr.dtype, *arr.shape)
...
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

This is ok:

```
In [515]: '{0} {1} {2}'.format(arr.dtype, *arr.shape)
Out[515]: 'float64 3 2'

In [533]: '{0!s} {1:d} {2:d}'.format(arr.dtype, *arr.shape)
Out[533]: 'float64 3 2'
```

For a 2d array, `arr.shape` is a 2 element tuple, and `*arr.shape` expands it.  SO with a 2d array, there are 3 arguments.

Now that you mention it `arr.data` does look funny.  I suspect they mean the whole data buffer content, but this particular attribute is the address, not the content.

As I mentioned in the comment, `np.save` does essentially the same thing, with a slightly larger initial block.  If this code is buggy, it would be wiser to stick with the tried-n-proven `np.save`.

Look at `np.lib.npyio.format` to see the full `np.save` code.  It writes a header, and then writes the databuffer with:

```
array.tofile(fp)
```

`np.load` uses `np.fromfile` if it can, but will fallback to using `frombuffer`.

---

In Py2 this works:

```
>>> arr=np.ones((2,3))
>>> b'{0:s} {1:d} {2:d}'.format(arr.dtype, *arr.shape)
'float64 2 3'
```