# Why npy(numpy array format) is faster to retrieve and use smaller disk size than pickle?

Tags: numpy, pickle, dataformat

I usually use `pickle` for saving and managing data.
However, I read the question and answers in stackoverflow
([best way to preserve numpy arrays on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619199/best-way-to-preserve-numpy-arrays-on-disk)), I realized that there are huge difference to computation and save it between `pickle` and `npy`.

Then, I have been tried to find the reason why, but I can't find it yet.

Are there anyone who know the thing make the difference?

Comment: Can you show some example code an some experiments that show the difference?

Comment: Without knowing specifics (which you can look up), pickle serializes way more stuff. It serializes full objects with their methods and everything, and I suppose each value is stored less efficiently, even for simple types (one extra byte for the type or something like that). In NumPy [npy format](http://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html), you basically have the shape of the array and then a long sequence of values one after another without additional overhead. Being a more goal-specific format, it can simplify things a lot.