# How to write a uint8 numpy array to compact file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to save a large uint8 numpy array for use later. How can I do that using the least amount of storage possible?

**Edit**: Encoding the file in UTF-8 or ASCII makes the file way larger than it needs to be.

Comment: Both questions that mark this as duplicate have essential differences in their main objectives. While in this question the OP is concerned about "storage usage", in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file the concern is "csv format" (larger than any binary file as mentioned) and in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619199/best-way-to-preserve-numpy-arrays-on-disk the concern is "speed on saving" (if fast is not going to be very efficient on storage usage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's [save_compressed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) will save the array into a **npz** file using  zip compression.

Apart from being compressed, it allows you also to save multiple arrays into the same file which might help you to save some space as well