# Best data structure for sparse data with multiple dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-xarray

I want to structure my data (similarly to `pandas`) to allow easy data exploration. I tried using `xarray.DataArray` for this task (the recommended way to represent n-dimensional data in `pandas` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel4d-and-panelnd-deprecated) but it appears inefficient given that my data is sparse. **Is there a better way to structure my data under `xarray.DataArray` or under another Python data structure to allow easy data exploration?**

**Description of data**

My data consists of prescriptions given to patients. Each entry consists of:

- Date (datetime64)
- Patient Id (int)
- Drug name (string)
- Drug type (string)
- Drug class (string)
- Scheduled dosage (real value)
- Dosage as needed (real value)

There might be several prescriptions on a date for different patients. A patient might also be prescribed several drugs (e.g., 2-3 drugs) at the same time with 'mandatory' dosage and 'optional/as needed' dosage. My dataset currently consists of 397 different patients, 1520 different dates and 161 different drugs. I only have 21790 non-null entries out of the 397*1520*161*2 entries (i.e., 0.01%).

**Initial code**

My data is currently organized as the following `xarray.DataArray`:

```
drugs = xarray.DataArray(dosages, coords={'patient': patients, 'time': dates, 
                                          'drug': drug_names, 'timing': timings, 
                                          'drug_type': ('drug', drug_types), 
                                          'drug_class': ('drug', drug_classes)},
                         dims=['patient', 'time', 'drug', 'timing'])
```

where `dosages.shape = (len(patients), len(dates), len(drug_names), 2)`. The `timing` axis corresponds to 'scheduled' vs. 'as needed' dosage. All the missing/zero entries are set to `numpy.nan`.

Comment: Assuming ~ 8 bytes per item, this would only be ~ 1.5 GB (e.g. `397*1520*161*2*8 / 2 ** 30`). This should fit comfortably in memory on almost any home PC, laptop, etc., and should be trivial on work / research / academic computing resources. Is memory the concern, or do you also want a suite of relational data algorithms (like the pandas API) but with native implementation for a sparse representation?

Comment: You might take a look at [h5py](https://www.h5py.org) and [PyTables](https://www.pytables.org); there's a good comparison [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883646/exporting-from-importing-to-numpy-scipy-in-sqlite-and-hdf5-formats) on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of version 0.10.2) xarray supports only dense arrays, but there is a Github issue https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1375 requesting sparse array support. A quick check of that issue suggests this is being actively worked on by enabling xarray to support the [sparse](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/latest/) module.